# Simple Database Structure to Incorporate Access to Records/Data Ownership

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, authorization

My question is about the best way to structure my database in a way that it is easy to check whether a certain user has rights to access a record. In my case, this applies to the best structure for a database with tables containing documents that can only be edited by certain users.

My database structure currently looks something like the following:

```
docs
{
  doc_id: uuid (primary key)
  name: varchar
  content: varchar
}
```

```
workgroup
{
  workgroup_id: uuid (primary key)
  name: varchar
}
```

```
workgroup_members
{
  workgroup_member_id: uuid (primary key)
  workgroup_id: uuid
  user_id: uuid
}
```

```
users
{
  user_id: uuid (primary key)
  name: varchar
}
```

For each document, there exist two possibilities:

1. Only a single user can edit a documents (he or she 'owns' the document)
2. A document can be 'assigned' to a workgroup, so that only members of that workgroup can edit the document. Now, the document does not have a single 'owner'

**What is the most simple yet effective way to embed this information in my tables?**

My initial thought was to structure my `docs` table in the following way:

```
docs
{
  doc_id: uuid (primary key)
  name: varchar
  content: varchar
  workgroup_id: uuid
  user_id: uuid
}
```

But then, either `workgroup_id` or `user_id` is always NULL. Also, the query to check if a user with a certain ID can edit the documents is not very straightforward. Also listing all documents a user works on becomes quite complex.

I also thought of not changing the `docs` table, but creating a `doc_access` table:

```
doc_access
{
  doc_access_id: uuid (primary key)
  doc_id: uuid
  user_id: uuid
}
```

This however, would create a lot of 'duplicate' information when a document is assigned to a workgroup, because all of the workgroup members need to be given access to the document. Also, I would need to run a query every time after document creation to add this 'extra' information to the doc_access table. Checking access with this table is easier though.

**Is there maybe a better/simpler way to store this relationship between users, workgroups and document access?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be hard-coding or implementing authorization in the database itself. Rather you should externalize the authorization logic to either a role-based access control system (RBAC) or, if you need finer grained authorization, attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)).

With ABAC, you have three parts:

- metadata (or **attributes**)

  - user metadata (their role, the projects they belong to, their clearance...)
  - resource metadata (project name, members...)
- **policies** that dictate how to combine the metadata
- an **architecture** that ties it all together

You can read more on [ABAC here](https://www.axiomatics.com/attribute-based-access-control/).

## Architecture

[image: Attribute Based Access Control]

## Policies

With ABAC, you can write policies in either of XACML or ALFA to dictate what you want to have happen. For instance:

```
          /**
           * R3 - An employee can edit a record they own, if it is in draft mode
           */
           rule employeeEdit{
               target clause user.role == "employee" and action.actionId == "edit" and record.status == "draft"
               condition  com.acme.record.owner == com.acme.user.employeeId 
               permit
           }
```